# floor() function in Crystal reports in Visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Hi I have a field in crystal Report to show 1.90 as 1 ,Is there any function to do this.Previously i have used round(1.90,0) i got as 2.But i want 1.Please suggest me the way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use truncate function to remove the decimal from the number

```
truncate(1.90)
```

result:

```
1
```